# Bootstrap popover not showing in Visualforce page inside apex:outputPanel and apex: repeat

Tags: visualforce, javascript, bootstrap

The bootstrap popover stopped showing up after I encased that part of the code inside of apex:outputPanel.

Here is my table. I render the panel after clicking on a row.

```
apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Case}" var="c">
                        <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/> 
                        <apex:column value="{!c.time}"/> 

                        <apex:actionSupport event="onRowClick" action="{!getList}" reRender="panel">
                        <apex:param name="rowId" value="{!c.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedCaseId}" />
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Here is the panel where I would like to have a popover when hovering over each breadcrumb.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="panel">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!hasList}">
            <div id="container">
                <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!processedList}" var="a">
                        <a href="#" class="{!IF(a.status=='Not Done','btn btn-danger',IF(a.status=='Done','btn btn-success','btn btn-info')))))}" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" data-content='Example popover text' type="button">
                            <span>{!a.status}</span>    
                        </a>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

I have already checked that I initiated the popover.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true
    }); 
});</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the content being rerendered? If so, you will need to re-bind your popover events in the `oncomplete` event for whatever is triggering the rerender.

Comment: @D.S. the oncomplete worked! The need to re-bind was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! I added a bit more detailed of an explanation as an answer so that you can accept it and help other people that run into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bootstrap javascript events with Visualforce, any `rerender` events on the page will break the bindings because Salesforce destroys the existing DOM elements, then re-draws them (sometimes differently, depending on your `rendered` statements). The simple solution to this is to re-bind bootstrap's events in the `oncomplete` of your action that invoked the `rerender`.